# Number of zoom levels in WMS?

Tags: wms, zoom, ogc

I want to calculate the numbers of zoom levels that has a WMS. I had a look to the [WMS spec](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=14416) and I guess that it has to be related with bounding box area and image size.

Comment: You can define the geographical area covered with BBOX and size of the output map with WIDTH and HEIGHT. As a result you can achieve any scale you want, including a possibility to have different scales in east-west and north-south directions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of zoom "levels" in the WMS specification, as there is for an XYZ/TMS. Rather, your WMS requests just use a bounding box which determines map scale.

Comment: Ok, maybe the correct term is scale instead zoom level. When you request a map to the server, depending on bbox you choose, the image back has a scale (meters/pixel). I want to know which is the max and min scale that the WMS provide.

Comment: Well, in principle the upper limit is the bounding box of the map service, which could be as big as (-180, -90, 180, 90) for a view of the entire world. If you wanted to, you could request a map representing a 1cm² bounding box on a projected view of the world. The scale is entirely determined from the bounding box you request, and which the service supports.