# Change the zoom level or detail level of a WMTS map from Swisstopo in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts, dpi

I'm using QGIS and I'd like to change the zoom level or detail level of my WMTS map. The WMTS connection I'm using is from Swisstopo and the URL is: https://wmts.geo.admin.ch/EPSG/2056/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml. Specifically, I'm interested in the "Landeskarten (farbig)" layer.

I'm aware that with WMTS services, the server usually controls the detail level, but is there a way to adjust this directly within QGIS?

I'd like to know how to make this adjustment and if there are specific steps or settings I should be aware of.

Comment: Please check out this post if that answers your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176271/number-of-zoom-levels-in-wms

Comment: The Swisstopo service  you are using is a WMTS not a WMS.  A WMS has no concept of zoom levels.